# Logic in if else statement to divide path if path shape is two or more '0'

Tags: paperjs

Hi all trying to write some logic in paper.js (also using opentype.js for font data) so that when a number contains two or more consecutive zeros' the zero path is divided so that it is solid.

**Things i know** a zero path, using my particular font, is made  up of an outer path with 19 segments and an inner path made up of 18 segments

So I thought would try to iterate over all paths check if a path has 19 segments and the next path has 18 segments and call path.unite() which kind of works. But I only want it to do this with consecutive '0' eg '100', '1000' but not 10.

So i was trying to do an if else statment where if-else (the current path has 18 segments and the next path is less than 18 segments) if true then do nothin or call path.divide()?

Im sure there is a way better way of doing this. Can you help please.

[link to codepen](https://codepen.io/limitedunlimited/pen/OJxVgvv)

```
paper.install(window);
window.onload = () => {
  paper.setup("canvas");
  opentype.load(
    "https://assets.codepen.io/1070/pphatton-ultralight-webfont.woff",
    (err, font) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        const fontPath = font.getPath("10k", 0, 100, 100).toSVG();
        const count = new paper.CompoundPath(fontPath);
        count.unite();
        count.children.forEach((child, i) => {
           if (
            child.segments.length === 19 &&
            count.children[i + 1].segments.length === 18
          ) {
            const eye = child.unite();
            eye.selected = true;
          } else if(
            count.children[i + 1].segments.length === 18
            && child.segments.length < 18
          ) {
            console.log('hello');
            // const target = child.divide();
            count.children[i].fillColor = 'black'
          } else{
            
          }
        });
        // const flatCount = count.children[1].unite()

        // console.log(count.children[2].segments.length)
        // const flatCountTwo = count.children[5].unite()
        // flatCount.translate(5,0)
        count.fillColor = "red";

        project.activeLayer.fitBounds(view.bounds.scale(0.6));
      }
    }
  );
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that rather than using `Font.getPath` to retrieve a single svg path for the whole text, you should use `Font.getPaths` to retrieve an svg path for each character.
This way you can quite simply do your analysis on the input string directly and handle the consecutive 0 differently than other characters.

---

### Edit

In order to detect the consecutive zeros, yes, you could use a regex or loop over the characters, like I did in the following example.
Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xidi2xidi/1jcu7yf0/) showcasing a possible solution.

```js
const handleZero = (path) => {
    path.children = path.children.slice(0, 1);
};

const getConsecutiveZerosIndices = (content) => {
    const zero = '0';
    return [...content]
        .map((char, i) => ({ char, i }))
        .filter(({ char, i }) => {
            const previousCharacter = content?.[i - 1];
            const nextCharacter = content?.[i + 1];
            return char === zero && (previousCharacter === zero || nextCharacter === zero);
        })
        .map(({ i }) => i);
};

const drawText = (content, font) => {
    const fontPaths = font.getPaths(content, 0, 100, 100);
    const consecutiveZerosIndices = getConsecutiveZerosIndices(content);
    const paths = fontPaths.map((fontPath, i) => {
        const path = new paper.CompoundPath(fontPath.toSVG());
        if (consecutiveZerosIndices.includes(i)) {
            handleZero(path);
        }
        return path;
    });
    const group = new paper.Group(paths);
    group.fillColor = 'red';
    return group;
};

const draw = (font) => {
    const path1 = drawText('10k', font);
    const path2 = drawText('100k', font);
    const path3 = drawText('1000k', font);

    path2.position = path1.position.add(0, path1.bounds.height * 1.2);
    path3.position = path2.position.add(0, path2.bounds.height * 1.2);

    paper.project.activeLayer.fitBounds(paper.view.bounds.scale(0.6));
};

paper.setup('canvas');
opentype.load(
    'https://assets.codepen.io/1070/pphatton-ultralight-webfont.woff',
    (err, font) => draw(font)
);
```

Comment: Thanks again Sasensi, that is a good shout. I'll give it a go but might comeback here. Do you mean using regex for example? Wondered if you wouldn't mind expanding?

Comment: I just tried Font.getPaths and got an error 'is not a function'. Maybe it has been deprecated?

Comment: see my edit answer for the full solution

Comment: Thats amazing and way better than regex! Thank you.

Comment: This is probably a dumb question but how do you go about constructing the many levels of code like this. Start at the last function and work backwards? Is there a good method to learn? Many thanks

Comment: Sorry to bother again. Could you explain what the purpose of .map(({ i }) => i); at the end of the getConsecutiveZerosIndices is please

Comment: Sorry worked it out, returns the indexes we need

Comment: Yeah, generally speaking, this kind of code is related to "functionnal programming" which you can easily learn about on the internet. About the methodology, I would say that there are 2 main possible approaches: either you first build a big code block and then spit it in multiple chunks in order to make it more readable / testable / maintainable. Either you first write the ideal code calling unexisting methods (a kind of pseudo code) and then implement them one by one, using unexisintg methods again if needed. Hoping this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the update.